# Precompile handlebars to html with WebPack

Tags: webpack, handlebars.js

I have WebPack set up to compile Handlebar templates.

The devServer works fine but it only generates main.js not a precompiled index.html

What am i missing? I essentially want what is outputted in the local server to be written to a html-file.

I have attached log and config-file below

```
> webpack-dev-server --config webpack-handlebars.config.js --mode=development

<i> [webpack-dev-server] Project is running at:
<i> [webpack-dev-server] Loopback: http://localhost:5000/
<i> [webpack-dev-server] Content not from webpack is served from '/Sites/dist' directory
<i> [webpack-dev-server] 404s will fallback to '/index.html'
<i> [webpack-dev-middleware] wait until bundle finished: /
asset main.js 458 KiB [emitted] (name: main)
asset index.html 8.82 KiB [emitted]
runtime modules 27.2 KiB 13 modules
modules by path ./node_modules/ 325 KiB 50 modules
modules by path ./handlebars/src/ 26.1 KiB
  modules by path ./handlebars/src/partials/includes/*.hbs 14.3 KiB
    ./handlebars/src/partials/includes/main-menu.hbs 6.38 KiB [built] [code generated]
    ./handlebars/src/partials/includes/hero.hbs 1.45 KiB [built] [code generated]
  ./handlebars/src/pages/page-one.hbs 6.2 KiB [built] [code generated]
  ./handlebars/src/partials/layouts/base.hbs 5.53 KiB [built] [code generated]
webpack 5.59.1 compiled successfully in 968 ms
```

```
const path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = (env) => {
    
    return {
        entry: "./handlebars/src/pages/page-one.hbs",
        output: {
            path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../dist'),
        },
        devServer: {
            static: {
                directory: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
            },
            port: 5000,
            open: true,
            historyApiFallback: true,
            devMiddleware: {
                writeToDisk: true
            }
        },
        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.hbs$/,
                    loader: "handlebars-loader",
                    options: {
                        partialDirs: [
                            path.join(__dirname, 'handlebars', 'src', 'partials')
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        plugins: [
            new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
                options: {
                    handlebarsLoader: {}
                }
            }),
            new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
                title: 'My awesome service',
                template: './handlebars/src/pages/page-one.hbs',
                outputFile: path.join(__dirname, 'dist/index.htm')
            })
        ]
    };
};
```